# Why are structures typedef'ed to their own names?

Tags: c++, typedef

In many places in code I have seen code like this:

```
typedef struct Name_of_Struct{
    //Things that the struct holds
} Name_of_Struct;
```

I don't seem to understand why such a declaration? Why is a struct `typedef`'ed to its own name? Isn't it like saying `typedef Name_of_struct Name_of_Struct;` ? I know there must be some reason behind such a declaration, as such instances of code are seen in good and highly used code bases like SDL.

Comment: Note that SDL is a C library that can be used from C++ as well.

Comment: First and foremost, this is a C-specific declaration pattern. C, not C++. You tagged your question as [C++]. So, did you see it in C++ code (which is possible in shared C/C++ code)? Or did you simply mistag your question?

Comment: I didn't know all that code was c. sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you don't have to do that

However in C this is done in order to save some typing

```
struct Name_of_Struct{
    //Things that the struct holds
} ;

struct Name_of_Struct ss; // If not typedef'ed you'll have to use `struct`
```

But with typedef

```
typedef struct Name_of_Struct{
    //Things that the struct holds
} Name_of_Struct;

Name_of_Struct ss ; // Simply just use name of struct, avoid struct everywhere
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is probably shared between C and C++.  The C Programming Language does not automatically create type names for user-created types (e.g., `enum`, `struct`, `union`).  I haven't written a lot of C in recent years so this may have been changed in C99.

Comment: Just curious as to where the initial down vote came from?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the name twice is redundant.

Originally in C the `typedef` was used so you didn't need to qualify the name with `struct` all the time. In C++ you can simply name the `struct`.

```
// C method

struct MyStruct {};

// need to qualify that name with `struct`

struct MyStruct s;

// C method avoiding typing `struct` all the time

typedef struct {} MyStruct;

MyStruct s; // no need to use `struct`

// C++ way

struct MyStruct {};

MyStruct s;
```

It seems some programmers have made a Frankenstein of the two methods.